# Is there a easy way to parallelize a foreach loop in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, foreach

Is there a easy way to parallelise a foreach loop in java 8 using some library stuff?

```
void someFunction(SomeType stuff, SomeType andStuff) {
    for (Object object : lotsOfObjects)
        object.doSomethingThatCanBeDoneInParallel(stuff, andStuff);
}
```

Multithreading is kinda painful and time consuming so i wonder if there is a simpler way to do the above using some library.

thanks.

edited in 3/06/2018

ExecutorServices is very handy indeed, I can't use shutdown() to wait because I run the thing every frame and create a new ExecutorServices every frame would be too expensive.

I ended up writing a class to parallelize a fori loop and I thought I share it with other newbies like me.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class ParallelForI {
    public ParallelForI(int numberOfThread) {
        NUMBER_OF_THREAD = numberOfThread;
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREAD);
        finished = new AtomicBoolean[NUMBER_OF_THREAD];
        for (int i = 0; i < finished.length; i++)
            finished[i] = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        // true is better for waitForLastRun before any run.
    }
    private ExecutorService executorService;
    private final int NUMBER_OF_THREAD;

    private AtomicBoolean[] finished;
    public void waitForLastRun() {
        synchronized (this) {
        /* synchronized outside the loop so other thread
         can't notify when it's not waiting. */
            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREAD; i++) {
                if (!finished[i].get()) {
                    i = -1;
                    try {
                        this.wait(); //
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // do nothing and move one.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void run(FunctionForI functionForI, final int MAX_I) {
        for (AtomicBoolean finished : finished)
            finished.set(false); // just started
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREAD; i++) {
            final int threadNumber = i;
            executorService.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override // use lambda if you have java 8 or above
                public void run() {
                    int iInitial = threadNumber * MAX_I / NUMBER_OF_THREAD;
                    int iSmallerThan;
                    if (threadNumber == NUMBER_OF_THREAD - 1) // last thread
                        iSmallerThan = MAX_I;
                    else
                        iSmallerThan = (threadNumber + 1) * MAX_I / NUMBER_OF_THREAD;
                    for (int i1 = iInitial; i1 < iSmallerThan; i1++) {
                        functionForI.run(i1);
                    }
                    finished[threadNumber].set(true);
                    synchronized (this) {
                        this.notify();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public interface FunctionForI {
        void run(int i);
    }
}
```

And this is the way to use it:

```
void someFunction(final SomeType stuff, final SomeType andStuff) {
    ParallelForI parallelForI = new parallelForI(numberOfThread);
    // swap numberOfThread with a suitable int

    parallelForI.run(new ParallelForI.FunctionForI() {
        @Override // use lambda if you have java 8 or above
        public void run(int i) {
            lotsOfObjects[i].doSomethingThatCanBeDoneInParallel(stuff, andStuff);
            // don't have to be array.
        }
    }, lotsOfObjects.length); // again, don't have to be array

    parallellForI.waitForLastRun(); // put this where ever you want 
    // You can even put this before parallelForI.run().
    // Although it doesn't make sense to do that...
    // Unlike shutdown() waitForLastRun() will not cause parallelForI to reject future task.
}
```

Comment: Agree on the idea of duplicate, but the answer is from 2014, can be updated ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be to launch every task in a `Thread` as follows:

```
new Thread(() -> object.doSomethingThatCanBeDoneInParallel(stuff, andStuff)).start();
```

but this is not a relevant solution as Thread creation is costly, so there are mechanisms and tools to help you: the `Executors` class to build some `pools`.

Once you have the instance that will manage this, you provide it with tasks, which will run in parallel, on the number of threads you choose:

```
void someFunction(SomeType stuff, SomeType andStuff) {
    ExecutorService exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);   // 4 can be changed of course
    for (Object object : lotsOfObjects) {
        exe.submit(() -> object.doSomethingThatCanBeDoneInParallel(stuff, andStuff));
    }

    // Following lines are optional, depending if you need to wait until all tasks are finished or not
    exe.shutdown();
    try {
        exe.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Comment: I love this community

Answer (score 1):

Use parallel streams. But this is not an universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

For loops in java are inherently serial. There is no way to do such thing with them. With the introduction of streams though, you can parallelize the operations on a collection using them.